# What is the Logic behind " i = (i + 1) % word.length "

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im new to Coding. can someone explain ("i = (i + 1) % word.length")

```
var text = document.querySelector('#text-wrap');

var word = text.getElementsByTagName('span');

var i = 0;

   function run(){

        word[i].style.display = 'none';

        i = (i + 1) % word.length

        word[i].style.display = 'initial';
  }

setInterval(run,800)
```

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator. Look that up since it's very useful!

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(i)` after that line and see what values `i` takes on.

Comment: `"%"` is the modulo operatior.  It's often used to implement `Do something every nth time.`:   You can learn more here: [Practical uses for the modulo operator](https://hatoum.com/blog/2012/12/practical-uses-for-modulo-operator.html)

Comment: In this case, the modulo operator is being used as essentially a shorthand for "increase `i` by 1 - but if it gets to `word.length` then reset it to 0". And this is done to make sure that `word[i]` always exists - it loops back to the beginning of the word after reaching the end.

Comment: Contrary to what is said above, `%` is the [*remainder* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder), not the modulo operator. There is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i < word.length - 1):

　　i = i + 1; // increment

else if (i == word.length - 1):

　　i = 0; // go back to 0
```

For example, if *word.length* is 5 and the initial *i* is 0, then

the output sequence of *i* is 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, ....

Answer (score 1):

It resets i to 0 ( to select the first word ) after the last word is selected.

```
var text = document.querySelector('#text-wrap');

var word = text.getElementsByTagName('span');

var i = 0;

   function run(){
        // hide i-th word
        word[i].style.display = 'none';
                // set i to
        // if the last word is selected select the first word ( reset to 0 )
        i = (i + 1) % word.length
                // display i-th word
        word[i].style.display = 'initial';
  }

setInterval(run,800)
```

I would not recommend doing it like this. An if statement is much clearer. This should do the same:

```
var text = document.querySelector('#text-wrap');
var word = text.getElementsByTagName('span');

var i = 0;

function run(){
   word[i].style.display = 'none';

    if( i+1 !== word.length )
      i++;
    else // if i+1 === word.length
      i = 0;

   word[i].style.display = 'initial';
}

setInterval(run,800)
```

Still you shouldn't use i as a global variable. At least use a variable name that is incredibly unlikely to exist in other code instead.

**a quick modulus explanation**

the modulus is what is leftover when you cannot iteratively remove an amount. Some examples:

`6 % 2 = 0 ( 6 - 2 - 2 - 2 = 0)`

`5 % 2 = 1 ( 5 - 2 -2 = 1 )`

`1 % 2 = 1 ( cannot substract 2 from 1 so the value is 1 )`

**simplified example**

```js
var word = [ '1', '2', '3'];
var i = 0;

function run(){
 console.log( word[i] );
    if( i+1 !== word.length )
      i++;
    else // if i+1 === word.length
      i = 0;
}

setInterval(run,1000);
```